# Want access files from multiple remote nodes to localhost machine in a single file?

Tags: ansible

I have three apache/httpd servers running on ansible remote nodes (multiple hosts). want to retrieve the logfiles from all the the nodes/hosts to the single file in a localhost machine. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can *cat* the content of the files and write to a local file?

```
  - shell: cat "{{remote_file}}"
    register: data
```

Then append the data to the single file in localhost

Comment: i have multiple files in different hosts, and want the content from those each files and pull to the single file in localhost ?